# bootstrapValidator and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

PROBLEM SOLVED:
i feel so bad!!!!!

I used the version 0.4.5 of bootstrapValidator and the event 'success.form.bv' can be used in the version 0.5.

### Sorry. Now it works.

i'm using bootstrapValidator and it works fine except when i want to use it with ajax.
The documentation speak about that:
http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ajax-submit/

The example is clear but it don't work. I don't even have the concole.log('Coucou' diplayed. So my ajax script won't work. However, my ajax script alone work fine.

```
<script>
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $('#formNouveauPatient').bootstrapValidator({
                                        message: 'Ce champ n\'est pas valide.',
                                        feedbackIcons: {
                                            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                                            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                                            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                                        },
                                        fields: {
                                            nom: {
                                                message: 'Nom incorrect',
                                                validators: {
                                                    notEmpty: {
                                                        message: 'Le nom est requis et ne peut être vide.'
                                                    },
                                                    stringLength: {
                                                        min: 3,
                                                        max: 30,
                                                        message: 'Le nom doit au moins contenir 3 caractères.'
                                                    },
                                                    regexp: {
                                                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_" "]+$/,
                                                        message: 'Le nom ne peut contenir que des lettes/chiffres/underscores'
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            email: {
                                                validators: {
                                                    emailAddress: {
                                                        message: 'Ce n\'est pas une adresse email valide.'
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
                                        // Prevent form submission
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        console.log('Coucou');

                                    });
                                });

                                /*
                                 $(function() {
                                //Fonction gère l'envoi du formulaire ajout de nouveau patient
                                    $("button#nouveauPatient").click(function(){
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "<?php echo WEBROOT; ?>/patient/ajoutPatient",
                                            data: $('form#formNouveauPatient').serialize(),
                                            success: function(msg){
                                                $("#Message").html(msg)
                                                $("#ModalNouveauPatient").modal('hide');    
                                            },
                                            error: function(){
                                                alert("Un problème est survenu durant la tentative d\'ajout.");
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                                */
                            </script>
```

Comment: how u corrected it.. can u give me the idea or full code to look into so that i can solve my problem too please

Comment: i updated to the version 0.5.